# Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel, eloquent

Есть такой кусок кода:

```
//get customer id
        $cust_id = Customer::where('email', \Auth::user()->email)->first()->id;
        //get massive of contractors id
        $contr_id = Fav_Contractor::select('contr_id')->where('cust_id', $cust_id)->get();
        //count massive elements
        $count = count($contr_id);

        //get all information about contractors, use id
        $contractors = [];
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $contractors[$i] = Contractor::where('id', $contr_id[$i]['contr_id'])->first();
        }
```

В нем я получаю сначала пользователя с одной таблицы, затем используя этот  id, я получаю массив id с другой таблицы. Далее, используя эти id мне нужно получить другие данные об этих пользователях с другой таблицы.
Я решил это так: 
-подсчитываем количество id 
-на основе количества делаем цикл 
-в цикле подставляя по одному id получаю информацию об одном пользователе 
Вот в чем вопрос:
Есть ли в Laravel Eloquent способ реализовать это без цикла, просто одним запросом, подставив массив получить тот же результат? Потому что в будущем, когда пользователей будет очень много, не хорошо повторять запрос к бд в цикле много раз.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, список полей в упомянутых таблицах

Comment: @VenZell Хорошо, вот: Fav_Contractors(id, cust_id, contr_id),  Contractor(id, firstname, lastname, company, cat_id, email, phone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, что у вас Laravel 5.0
Если это не так, посмотрите документацию для своей версии

Добавьте корректные связи между моделями

```
class Customer extends Model {

    public function favContractors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Fav_Contractor', 'cust_id');
    }

}

class Fav_Contractor extends Model {

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Customer', 'cust_id');
    }

    public function contractor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Contractor', 'contr_id');
    }

}

class Contractor extends Model {

    public function favContractors()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Fav_Contractor', 'contr_id');
    }

}
```

Затем в вашем контроллере используйте активную загрузку [eng](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) | [rus](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/eloquent#%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F):

```
$customer = Customer::where('email', \Auth::user()->email)->first();

// Получаем коллекцию контракторов, перебирать можно foreach
// \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection

$contractors = $customer->with(['favContractors.contractor'])->get();
```

1. К сожалению, мне достоверно неизвестно, как поведет себя Laravel с именем модели `Fav_Contractor`. Обычно используется `CamelCase` именование.
2. Мне неизвестно, какие поля у вас уникальные. Возможно нужно будет скорректировать некоторые связи с `hasMany` на `hasOne`

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно, как раз узнаю о активной загрузке.